# Phase shift problems with ICL7611 op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, non-inverting

Update: This problem has been solved, the error was in another circuit that was providing the current and not with this. Note to everyone (and self): ACS712 is direction sensitive, even for AC currents. Connecting in the opposite way gives a 180 degree phase shift in the current.

I am using the ICL7611 op-amp to add DC to an AC signal. In a non-inverting amplifier configuration. The output looks good on magnitude, but is shifted by nearly 90 degrees in phase.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFS8Zo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how my output is looking (Red is Voltage, Green is current). Normalized in magnitude.
[image]

While reading the datasheet of ICL7611, I found this piece of information.

[image]

Does it mean, the IC is adding a phase shift? If yes, how do I compensate it? If no, Why am I getting this phase shift?  Thanks.

Comment: That is **not** a 90 degree phase shift you see, it is 180 degrees, the signal is inverted. Stop thinking about compensating for it, always first find out what is going on. Compensating for everything results in bad designs so loose that habit. You probably switched the inputs or plotted the voltages in the wrong way.

Comment: Oops, I am sorry. Still, connecting in a non-inverting configuration must give me an in-phase signal. Why am I getting a 180 degree phase shift? Also, I am using the ACS712 to collect the current data.

Comment: Correct, a non-inverting amplifier will not phase-shift a signal which is low enough in frequency. 50 Hz is low enough in that respect. Sure the freq. response graph shows some phase shift at 50 Hz but that is for **open loop** not closed loop like when using feedback !!! I see no ACS712 in your schematic so you're not telling the whole story. You must have some signal inversion somewhere in your setup.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Problem solved, thanks! It is weird though, the problem was with ACS712. Despite being an AC current sensor, swapping the current wires from Line to Neutral did the trick!

Comment: Nothing weird about that, the ACS712 is a current sensor so depending on the direction of the current you get an inverterted signal or not. It being an AC sensor means it can detect positive and negative currents, or in different words: currents in either direction. The polarity of the output signal indicates the direction of the current. Nothing weird, makes perfect sense.